# Custom Tag Helper - replace the html tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've created a Tag Helper that reads a txt file that contains meta tags and writes the content to the page.
But the original tag doesn't change after Process is executed.
I want to completely replace the original tag with the content of the txt file.

**Tag Helper**

```
[HtmlTargetElement("LC_meta")]
public class MetaTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _env;

    [HtmlAttributeName("filename")]
    public string Filename { get; set; } = "default.txt";

    public MetaTagHelper(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
       output.Content.SetContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "META", this.Filename)));
    }
}
```

**and this is the original tag's:**

```
<LC_meta />
<LC_meta filename="sample.txt" />
```

I'm kinda stuck, so many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you add the taghelper to the view/razor page?

Comment: Your target element is LC_meta, but your element name is meta. Have you tried changing it to `[HtmlTargetElement("meta")]`?

Comment: I've updated the code since I posted to match LC_meta, but still no go. I put a break point in the Process method that hits so I know the tag helper is invoked, but the tag still remains the same. Is SetContent the right method to use?

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried removing the call to `base.Process(context, output)`?

Comment: Yes, I started without the base call. It's there because I found it in a sample, but I dont know if I actually need it..

Comment: Judging by the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime/TagHelpers/TagHelper.cs#L43) it does nothing :)

Comment: yeah look at that. its now removed :) but still same result..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to omit the tag, then just set the tagname to NULL and write the text:

```
public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    output.TagName = null;
    output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;
    output.PostContent.SetContent("<h1>this gets HTML encoded<h1>");
    output.PostContent.SetHtmlContent("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
}
```

or if you want to change the tag name, set the tagname to something else:

```
public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    output.TagName = "pre";
    output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;
    output.PostContent.SetContent("<h1>this gets HTML encoded<h1>");
    output.PostContent.SetHtmlContent("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
}
```

Also, be sure your cshtml file contains

```
@addTagHelper *, ASSEMBLY_NAME_OF_CLASS_WITH_TAGHELPER
```

at the beginning (before layout), e.g.

```
@addTagHelper *, BlueMine
```

Comment: What is a difference between the `SetContent` and the `SetHtmlContent`?

Comment: SetContent does HtmlEncode the content. SetHtmlContent does not. In other words, if you want to put custom markup, use SetHtmlContent, if you just want to put a label-text, use SetContent.