ASP .NET Core - Extending @Html.EditorFor to append <span>
I am porting an old .NET 4.8 app to .NET Core and the old app has custom code which extends the @Html.EditorFor to wrap the <input> within a  and appends a <span> after the <input> tag (basically to add a "%" sign after the input field).  I have added the older code below.
public static MvcHtmlString Addon(this MvcHtmlString htmlText, string text, string classes)
{
    var wrapper = new TagBuilder("div");
    wrapper.AddCssClass("input-group");
    wrapper.AddCssClass(classes);
    wrapper.InnerHtml = htmlText.ToHtmlString();
    var span = new TagBuilder("span");
    span.AddCssClass("input-group-addon");
    span.InnerHtml = text;
    wrapper.InnerHtml += span.ToString();

    return new MvcHtmlString(wrapper.ToString());
}

The above code is used in conjunction with the @Html.EditorFor as below.
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PercentageOfControlledSubstances, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control short-textfield percent" } }).**Addon**("%", "med-textfield")

When compiling I get an error stating:

Reference to type 'HtmlString' claims it is defined in 'System.Web', but it could not be found.

Below is a screenshot of what the final rendering should look like.

I know this is a conversion from .NET 4.8 to .NET Core and I have been searching how to convert my code but cannot find documentation on how to do this in .NET Core. After a lot of searching, it looks like .NET Core uses either IHtmlContent or HtmlHelper(s) but I am unsure - since I can find no documentation.

I guess a secondary question (and might be a primary one) is in ASP.Net Core should the @Html tag helpers even be used or is there a better solution for the newer framework?

For .NET Core, you need to migrate from MvcHtmlString which only supports .NET Framework MVC to IHtmlContent.
The implementation is almost similar, just need to migrate following:



No
.NET Framework MVC
.NET Core MVC




1
HtmlMvcString
IHtmlContent


2
Append HTML with <Tag Builder instance>.InnerHtml += <HTML string>
Apend HTML with <Tag Builder instance>.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(<HTML string>)


3
Retrieve parsed HTML from Html.Editor() with htmlText
Retrieve parsed HTML from Html.Editor() by using StringWriter


4
Return value with MvcHtmlString instance
Return value with HtmlString instance



using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;

public static class HtmlHelperEditorExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlContent Addon(this IHtmlContent htmlContent, string text, string classes)
    {
        var wrapper = new TagBuilder("div");
        wrapper.AddCssClass("input-group");
        wrapper.AddCssClass(classes);

        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            htmlContent.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
            wrapper.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(writer.ToString());
        }

        var span = new TagBuilder("span");
        span.AddCssClass("input-group-addon");
        span.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(text);

        wrapper.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(span);

        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            wrapper.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
            return new HtmlString(writer.ToString());
        }
    }
}


Worked perfectly.

To address your comment in your original post:

I guess a secondary question (and might be a primary one) is in ASP.Net Core should the @Html tag helpers even be used or is there a better solution for the newer framework?

tl;dr
ASP.NET Core introduced Tag Helpers as an alternative to HTML Helpers (but "don't replace HTML Helpers"). Tag Helpers improve readability, can help reduce coding errors, and "produce more robust, reliable, and maintainable code".
<input asp-for="PercentageOfControlledSubstances"
   class="form-control short-textfield percent" 
   data-addon-text="%" data-addon-class="med-textfield" />

The InputTagHelper HTML above is equivalent to the @Html.EditorFor HTML Helper from the original .NET Framework 4.8 code in your post.
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PercentageOfControlledSubstances, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control short-textfield percent" } }).Addon("%", "med-textfield")

Along with their respective extension override methods (in @YongShun's post for the HTML Helper and below in this post for the Tag Helper), the same HTML output is produced:
<div class="input-group med-textfield">
    <input aria-label="Percentage of controlled substances" class="form-control short-textfield percent text-box single-line" id="PercentageOfControlledSubstances" name="PercentageOfControlledSubstances" title="Percentage of controlled substances" type="text">
    <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
</div>

Adding aria-, title, or any other attributes
The attributes in the EditorFor HTML Helper in your original post doesn't include the title attribute or aria- attributes that Chrome DevTools calls out as an accessibility issue. This SO post insight into using one versus the other or both.
Adding these attributes to the EditorFor HTML Helper:
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PercentageOfControlledSubstances, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control short-textfield percent", title = "Percentage of controlled substances", aria_label = "Percentage of controlled substances" } }).Addon("%", "med-textfield")

The length of the @Html.EditorFor() helper gets much longer. Also note that attributes that have a dash (-) in its name (e.g. aria-label) must replace dashes with underscores (e.g. aria_label).
Adding new attributes to the input tag helper is, of course, simply adding attributes to HTML elements:
<input asp-for="PercentageOfControlledSubstances"
   class="form-control short-textfield percent" 
   title="Percentage of controlled substances"
   aria-label="Percentage of controlled substances"
   data-addon-text="%" data-addon-class="med-textfield" />

Process override extension
Similar to the HtmlHelperEditorExtensions class in @YongShun's answer, Tag Helpers provide a process override by implementing the ITagHelper interface on a class declaration.
In the input Tab Helper above, the attribute data-addon-text triggers the override method that will replace the original HTML with the add-on HTML.
The following [HtmlTargetElement] attribute on the extension class sets the conditions for executing the Process override method: An <input> tag containing the attribute data-addon-text.
[HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = "data-addon-text")]
public class AddonAttributeTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        ...
    }
}

AddonAttributeTagHelper.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

namespace WebApplication1.Helpers
{
    // Add the following to the file '_ViewImports.cshtml' in the
    // 'Pages' folder or add the following line to the top of the
    // Razor page that contains an '<input>' tag with the custom
    // data attribute 'data-addon-text'.
    // @addTagHelper WebApplication1.Helpers.AddonAttributeTagHelper, WebApplication1

    [HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = "data-addon-text")]
    public class AddonAttributeTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            // Get addon text
            output.Attributes.TryGetAttribute("data-addon-text", out TagHelperAttribute addonTextAttr);
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(addonTextAttr.Value.ToString())) { return; }
            string? addonText = addonTextAttr.Value.ToString();

            // Get addon class name(s)
            output.Attributes.TryGetAttribute("data-addon-class", out TagHelperAttribute addonClassAttr);
            string? addonClass = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(addonClassAttr?.Value?.ToString()) ? "" : addonClassAttr?.Value.ToString();

            // Remove 'data-addon-' attributes before retrieving original HTML
            output.Attributes.Remove(addonTextAttr);
            output.Attributes.Remove(addonClassAttr);

            // Write original HTML to 'origHmtl' variable
            StringWriter writer = new();
            output.WriteTo(writer, System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder.Default);
            string origHtml = writer.ToString();

            // Set addon HTML using original HTML, addon class name, and addon text
            string addonHtml = $"<div class='input-group {addonClass}'>{origHtml}<span class='input-group-addon'>{addonText}</span></div>";

            // Replace original tag with contents of 'addonHtml' variable
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43463145/custom-tag-helper-replace-the-html-tag
            output.TagName = null;
            output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;
            output.PostContent.SetHtmlContent(addonHtml);
        }
    }
}

Razor page
@page
@model WebApplication1.Pages.ExtendingHtmlEditorForModel
@using WebApplication1.Helpers;
@addTagHelper WebApplication1.Helpers.AddonAttributeTagHelper, WebApplication1

<p>Extending Html.EditorFor to append span</p>

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PercentageOfControlledSubstances, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control short-textfield percent", title = "Percentage of controlled substances", aria_label = "Percentage of controlled substances" } }).Addon("%", "med-textfield")

<p>Tag Helper</p>

<input asp-for="PercentageOfControlledSubstances"
       class="form-control short-textfield percent" 
       title="Percentage of controlled substances"
       aria-label="Percentage of controlled substances"
       data-addon-text="%" data-addon-class="med-textfield" />

Error handling
The Process override method above handles the following cases: Empty text for the add-on class attribute; empty text for the add-on text attribute; missing add-on text attribute. In the last case, the Process override method is never called because the HTML element does not match the condition of:
[HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = "data-addon-text")]

on the extension class.
<input asp-for="PercentageOfControlledSubstances"
       class="form-control short-textfield percent" 
       data-addon-text="%" data-addon-class="" />

<input asp-for="PercentageOfControlledSubstances"
       class="form-control short-textfield percent" 
       data-addon-text="" data-addon-class="med-textfield" />

<input asp-for="PercentageOfControlledSubstances"
       class="form-control short-textfield percent" 
       data-addon-class="med-textfield" />

Documentation
From Microsoft's documentation for Tag Helpers in ASP.NET Core:

Tag Helpers enable server-side code to participate in creating and rendering HTML elements in Razor files. ... If you're familiar with HTML Helpers, Tag Helpers reduce the explicit transitions between HTML and C# in Razor views. In many cases, HTML Helpers provide an alternative approach to a specific Tag Helper, but it's important to recognize that Tag Helpers don't replace HTML Helpers and there's not a Tag Helper for each HTML Helper. Tag Helpers compared to HTML Helpers explains the differences in more detail.

Under the heading 'What Tag Helpers provide' in the same documentation linked above, Microsoft lists the following benefit:

An HTML-friendly development experience: For the most part, Razor markup using Tag Helpers looks like standard HTML. Front-end designers conversant with HTML/CSS/JavaScript can edit Razor without learning C# Razor syntax.

In your post, the editor for the property PercentageOfControlledSubstances is an <input> element.

the  element ... contains the asp-for attribute. This attribute extracts the name of the specified model property into the rendered HTML.

The documentation provides information that compares Tag Helpers and HTML Helpers here.
This doc goes into detail about creating a Process override method, similar to the Process method above.
